# Using Biblatex, how can I cite different sources differently?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am working on a document where I want to cite one source in one specific way and all the other sources in a different way. More specifically, I want to cite the source named "drama" like this:

> "some citation from the drama" (p. 54)

whilst all the other sources shall be cited like this:

> "now something else" (Shakespeare, Hamlet, p. 123)

How can I achieve this?

Currently, all my citations are done with the `\autocite` command.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See `bib by category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to suppress all citation output for a particular work. But then you have to be careful to only cite this work with page references.

In the example below we suppress `sigfridsson`. The implementation here is for the `authoryear` style. Other styles can be handled similarly (at least in principle), but the exact implementation will look different and may be significantly more complex.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\ifhidecite}{\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{sigfridsson}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifhidecite
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\ifhidecite
       {\PackageWarning{biblatex}{%
          Hidden citation without postnote.\MessageBreak
          The citation outout may look weird}}
       {}}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{postnotedelim}}%
     \printfield{postnote}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite[45]{sigfridsson}

\autocite[380]{worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (p. 45)]

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. As a follow-up now: I am using a custom citation style called "uni-wtal-ger", which is based upon biblatex-dw.

Within this style, I would like to quote everything as set up by the style and all sources in {drama} as mentioned above. How can I change the references to the drama to be rendered as parenthesis rather than footnotes?

Comment: @Floris I suggest you ask a new question about that. But, please include a short example document (similar to the one posted in this answer) that shows your current bibliography and citation setup.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to include every page reference to the topic drama in an index.  In that case you could use a hack like this snippet of code:

> . . . from the drama'' (p.~54)